# ¿Cuál es el significado de "Sánchez se LA juega al todo o nada con Iglesias"?

Tags: verbos, significado, verbo-pronominal

¿A qué se refiere "la" en el título de un [artículo que he encontrado](https://www.elespanol.com/espana/20190709/sanchez-juega-iglesias-cede-sometera-verano-desgaste/412209869_0.amp.html)?

> Sánchez se **la** juega al todo o nada con Iglesias: o cede ya o lo someterá a un verano de desgaste.

Perdonen por no saber cómo agregar el enlace al título.

Comment: Nada que perdonar, nadie nade aprendido :) Se trata de seleccionar un texto y luego apretar en Contrl+L para añadir el enlace.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por su consejo, fedorqui! Pero de momento  no tengo más opción que usar un teléfono inteligente. ¿Sabe usted cómo hacerlo en este caso? ¿Y añadir un color distintivo al fondo de una cita? 

Comment: mira en https://spanish.stackexchange.com/editing-help, ¡hay muy buenas explicaciones!

Comment: Cuando tengo prisa pongo el enlace brutamente en el texto.  (Es mejor que nada....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi entendimiento es que "la" se refiere a "la vida" (en sentido real o figurado). De hecho, se encuentran en Internet varios ejemplos de "jugarse **la vida** a todo o nada":

- El TDK Manresa, naming de los visitantes en aquella época, venció por 61-62 en el Juan Ríos Tejera, sentenció la serie al mejor de cinco partidos con un 3-1 a su favor y condenó a los aurinegros a jugarse **la vida** a todo o nada en un play out definitivo contra el OAR Ferrol, que acabaría con los canaristas descendidos a Primera B. ([Fuente 1](https://cbcanarias.net/2015/11/26/el-canarias-manresa-un-clasico-ochentero-con-muchas-historias-detras/))
- Había decidido abandonar toda lógica y jugarse **la vida** a todo o nada. ([Fuente 2](https://deloquenoestaescrito.wordpress.com/2018/03/12/cafe-solo-contigo-ii/))
- Sin la acuciante necesidad del fervor

  Sin la desgracia de tener que sentir desamor

  Sin la osadía de jugarse la vida a todo o nada ([Fuente 3](http://plumaslatinoamericanas.blogspot.com/2017/03/ofrenda.html))
- Su interpretación de un hombre que ha decidido jugarse **la vida** a todo o nada en general es más que correcta, pero es en la fantástica última escena cuando llega a lo más alto. ([Fuente 4](http://www.lacabezadealfredogarcia.com/2013/08/20/atraco-perfecto/))
- Una mujer, también, dispuesta a jugarse **la vida** a todo o nada. ([Fuente 5](http://www1.ucol.mx/hemeroteca/pdfs/070602.pdf))

Obviamente, es mucho más común la expresión "jugársela a todo o nada", con el referente omitido.

Agregado: Se me ocurre que "la" también puede referirse a "la suerte". En Internet se encuentran algunos ejemplos de "jugarse la suerte a todo o nada", por caso:

- Se trabajaba en el feudo con la familia ampliada, no quedaba la suerte de cada uno atada a un destino sólo personal, en el cual se juega **la suerte** a todo o nada. ([Fuente 6](http://www.inif.ucr.ac.cr/recursos/docs/Revista%20de%20Filosof%C3%ADa%20UCR/Vol.%20XXXI/No.%2076/Roberto%20A.%20Follari.%20Sobre%20la%20construccion%20hist%C3%B2rica%20de%20la%20razon%20occidental.pdf))

Answer (score -2):

La locución se encuentra en el mejor diccionario de español en todo el mundo:
El Diccionario de la lengua española de la Academia Real

jugársela, o jugárselas a alguien

1. locs. verbs. **Comportarse con él mal o de modo desleal**.

[Real Academia](https://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=MaeD6rF)

Me parece razonable decir que ***la*** se refiere a una situación que se puede deducir de un contexto X (que aparece en el contexto del discurso del locutor).

Comment: Buena referencia, pero en este caso no está usando esta acepción (aunque lo mismo acabe usándola), sino más bien la de "jugársela" en el sentido de "apostarlo todo a una cosa". Por ejemplo en el contexto de que estemos haciendo cavilaciones sobre el futuro yo podría decir "me la juego, yo creo que el Barça ganará la liga de fútbol".

Comment: Aqui es: jugársela a **todo o nada**=intentar todo que pueda para derrumbarlo y en donde ganará todo o perderá todo. Además, el título lo dice: o cede ya o lo someterá a un verano de desgaste. El título es repetitivo...someter alguién a un verano así es jugada "sucia". O sea, refleja la definición de la RAE.

Comment: Es una expresión que siempre es con "la", no importa el contexto y no hace falta. Se le puede decir a alguien de pronto "Te la estás jugando".

Comment: @cdlvcdlv Lo sé. (suspiro) Sin embargo, no veo ningún inconveniente en hacer una tal lectura del pronombre la. Es razonable.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!

Comment: No es "El Diccionario de la lengua española de la **Academia Real**" sino "el  Diccionario de la lengua española, de la **Real Academia Española**". El orden a veces es importante

Comment: @user28386 Ha desaparecido.